# Cache-Control headers repeated; valid or not? (Nginx)

Tags: nginx, cache-control

I've got a resource in my Nginx that is configured like this:

```
location ~ foo\.js$ {
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    expires 1d;
}
```

If I open this with Firebug and look at the headers it shows this:

```
Cache-Control   max-age=86400, public
```

The site is using HTTPS so I want to make sure I get it right because apparently browsers don't cache it unless it's max-age>0 AND `public`. [See this](http://hoisie.com/post/yes_browsers_do_cache_ssl_resources__so_please_use_googles_cdn)

But what happens with my Nginx when I use `curl -Ik https://...` is that it says:

```
...
Expires: Sat, 22 Jan 2011 18:23:36 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Cache-Control: public
...
```

It repeats the `Cache-Control` header! Clearly Firebug doesn't mind. But is it right?

Is there a perhaps a better way to set `Expires` and `Cache-Control` (with `public`) in one just two lines?

Comment: Are you sure about needing max-age and public? According to the spec (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), section 14.9.3 states that "The max-age directive on a response implies that the response is cacheable (i.e., "public") unless some other, more restrictive cache directive is also present."

Answer (score 49):

Yes, it's valid and equivalent to use multiple Cache-Control headers.

From the [HTTP 1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2):

> Multiple message-header fields with
>   the same field-name MAY be present in
>   a message if and only if the entire
>   field-value for that header field is
>   defined as a comma-separated list
>   [i.e., #(values)]. It MUST be possible
>   to combine the multiple header fields
>   into one "field-name: field-value"
>   pair, without changing the semantics
>   of the message, by appending each
>   subsequent field-value to the first,
>   each separated by a comma.

It's easy to verify that this provision applies to the Cache-Control header because of [how it's defined](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9):

> Cache-Control   = "Cache-Control" ":" 1#cache-directive

To understand how to interpret the line above, see the spec's [notational conventions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html). The `1#` means "a comma-separated list of one or more".

Comment: So, it is valid based on the HTTP spec, but the real question is how do popular browsers and proxies deal with multiple Cache-Control headers? The latest-and-greatest probably handle it correctly, but Firefox in particular seems to not cache whenver there is anything "uncommon" about your cache-control header setup.
Anybody have a link to a good test of this? I hate to do it myself if it's already been done ;-)

Comment: The notational convention I missed when reading the spec was that 1#cache-directive means a comma separated list of one or more cache directives.  So to narrow in, see "#rule" in the [notational conventions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html)

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem on different configuration.
This is what currently works for me.

Example taken from [Module ngx_http_headers_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html)

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    application/octet-stream   max;
    ~image/                    max;
}

server {
        expires $expires;
        ....
}
```

Comment: Not exactly the answer to the question asked but highly relevant, IMO.

Comment: Also it doesn't work anymore
```
    Cache-Control: max-age=3600\n
    Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=3600```

config says:
```
        expires 1h;\n
        add_header Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=3600";``` (sorry about formatting)