# Multiple "max-age" cache control headers in response

Tags: asp.net, cache-control

If a web response contains a cache control header like:

Cache-Control:public, no-cache="Set-Cookie", **max-age=1800,max-age=3600**

Which max-age will be used by the browser?

If it matters, my code is .NET/IIS.  1800 is being set in the code for a specific http handler, and 3600 is being set in IIS for all requests.

Comment: How are you setting the custom max-age in your http handler?

Comment: context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));

Comment: Yes, it's valid. Answer can be found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762377/cache-control-headers-repeated-valid-or-not-nginx

Comment: I can see its valid, but  my question is which value will the browser use if the same field appears multiple times?  The first, the last, different for each browser? I haven't had the time to test every browser yet.

Comment: I'm working on a development environment that adds `max-age=0` to every request. So my `cache-control`-header will look like this: `Cache-Control: max-age=120, max-age=0`. But what will happen then? How do I know which one it'll use?

Answer (score 3):

Per [RFC 7234, section 4.2.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-4.2.1), this header is not valid, as the `max-age` directive appears more than once:

> When there is more than one value present for a given directive
> (e.g., two Expires header fields, multiple Cache-Control: max-age
> directives), the directive's value is considered invalid.  Caches are
> encouraged to consider responses that have invalid freshness
> information to be stale.

Clients are not *required* to reject it, but the specification encourages it.

> Which max-age will be used by the browser?

According to the spec: none of them. Some browsers diverge from this behaviour, but this is browser-specific behaviour.

(The [cache-tests.fyi HTTP Caching Tests](https://cache-tests.fyi/) capture [results](https://cache-tests.fyi/#cc-parse) for [this case](https://github.com/http-tests/cache-tests/blob/84a3fa528d11bbf9a93b09ed9056690a69272eb2/tests/cc-parse.mjs), which suggest that Chrome and Safari use the first value, whereas Firefox uses the second.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is even valid. I would say that different browsers might behave differently in that case, so you pretty much would need to test and find out.

It might be a good idea for your handler to simply override the default max-age value instead of adding another one.

Answer (score 0):

What I am understanding (which may not be correct) from the chromium implementation, if it is not failing somewhere before the step of parsing of max-age due to multiple max-age definitions, "the last one parsed successfully" will be effective. Logically I'm not expecting any browser implementation to compare the values and select the least/most value since the directive itself seems illogical.