# Slim v3 duplicates cache-control header

Tags: php, caching, header, slim, cache-control

I have to return a specific cache-control header (`Cache-Control: public, max-stale=13910400`) but when run this, I get this: [image: Curl -v]

Cache-control has been duplicated, but I only need custom values.

```
$newResponse = $response->withHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-stale=13910400')->withJson($appInfo);
return $newResponse;
```

I tried this but it doesn't work (just for testing):

```
$newResponse = $response->withoutHeader('Cache-Control')->withHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-stale=13910400')->withJson($appInfo);
return $newResponse;
```

How can I set the header correctly?

Thank you

Comment: I've reported about the problem to the Slim authors: https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/issues/2282

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you might have a middleware problem.

Your code above does produce the correct output.

```
$app->get('/test', function ($req, $res, $args) {
    header_remove("Cache-Control"); //Edit <--
    $newResponse = $res->withHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-stale=13910400')->withJson(["message" => "Test"]);
    return $newResponse;
});
```

CURL Output

> C:\Users\Glenn>curl -X GET -v http://localhost/vms2/public/test
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Date: Tue, 13 Sep 2016 19:04:42 GMT * Server Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.6.3 is not blacklisted
>
> Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.6.3
>
> X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.3
>
> Set-Cookie: VMS2=2qf14qr1c0eplgfvibi8t2hcd2; path=/
>
> Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
>
> Pragma: no-cache
>
> Cache-Control: public, max-stale=13910400
>
> Content-Length: 18
>
> Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
>
> {"message":"Test"}
>
> - Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

Comment: Watch your code. There are 2 cache-control, like me.

Comment: interesting... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762377/cache-control-headers-repeated-valid-or-not-nginx apparently it's valid ?

Comment: I usually use postman and its exactly like firebug, but I only want the public and max-stale appears. Btw I use apache, if its relevant

Comment: Slim doesn't set any defaults , which makes me believe its apache or php doing it... I haven't been able to find any docs on php doing it.

Comment: It's php, that's adding the first one... I have updated my answer with how to get rid of it :)

Answer (score 0):

remove the cache control from your code and add the below code in your .htaccess file

`<filesMatch "\\.(html|htm|php)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>`