# How to fix error "Failed to load ressource : Acces-control-allow-origin cannot contain more than one origin"

Tags: ios, api, nginx, cors, symfony4

We have recently engaged an external company to develop a mobile application for us.

we've made an API available for them, but they're having problems compiling the iOs executable. (everything works fine under androïd)

The error message they receive is: "Failed to load resource: Access-Control-Allow-Origin cannot contain more than one origin "

We use symfony 4, Nelmio CORS and a nginx configuration.

We added this to our nginx configuration, but the problem persists (https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html) ("Authorization" has been added on GET and POST method), and i honestly don't know what do i have to do to help them.

Do you have any idea about this? Is this a server problem? or a development problem on their side? on ours ?

They use Cordova with ionic and WKWebView.
WKWebView seems to cause problem once they've enabled CORS.

I've check my Api response, and it's showing the good value : [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBmhh.png)

I am at your disposal if you wish to obtain additional information

Comment: This could be caused if the header has multiple values `*,*` for example. Or the header is set multiple times at different places [for example, once by NGINX and once by whatever the NGINX routes the request to]. [See this SO question for a deep discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762377/cache-control-headers-repeated-valid-or-not-nginx). As to where the issue is I'm pretty certain that this must be resolved on the server side.

Comment: Are there any known methods to see where those additionnal headers are added ? i saw nothing under POSTMAN, except the allowed origin * which is already configured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This time it was not a server side issue.

Double Header Access Control => only when running command

```
ionic cordova run [android/ios] —livereload
```

and accessing API, iOS problems :

Allow-navigation and Allow-intent added in confix.xml > iOS platform :

```
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Comment: Hi D.TOUAUX, but in case we don't use the first command, but we deploy directly onto the device: there is a way to avoid that error ? 
(for example in production mode, we cannot run app like that)

Thanks in advance