# Headers with same key like cache-control gets combined in a single line

Tags: reactjs, express, http-headers, axios, next.js

I am developing a Server-side rendering app using Express, NextJS and React and for API calls I am using Axios. I am developing it using Typescript. So using Axios with Typescript. I have a requirement where I have to append some headers in my SSR page response (`ctx.res`) based on some API response. I am able to achieve this and is able to set headers received from one API to my final SSR page. Though there is one issue I am facing which is related to the combination of `cache-control` header.

The actual API response I get from `wget --save-headers <endpoint>` is :

```
Cache-Control: public,max-age=3600
Cache-Control: s-maxage=34871
```

I have 2 `cache-control` keys in separate lines and I want it to be appended same way in my SSR page response header.
When I do console of `response.headers` just after the API call (via Axios) my same header is printed as below and so in my SSR page response, only one cache-control header is appending.

```
'cache-control': 'public,max-age=3600, s-maxage=34871'
```

I am not sure where this combination of cache-control header is taking place. How I can resolve this so that I am able to send my headers same way I received from the API (When I did wget).
Is it Axios combining the headers?

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762377/cache-control-headers-repeated-valid-or-not-nginx, it might answer your query.